# Python: Retry some lines of code without using function

Tags: python, pytest

In tests, I have to wait (`using time.sleep(30)`) to assert expected results but adding sleep in many tests takes too much time while running tests. So the idea came to mind is `polling`, i.e. keep on checking the results for a specific timeout and then raise or we will get the expected result and test will pass. For now I am using [polling](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/polling/) package and I have to create a function with my assertion code and then pass this callback to `polling` and specify timeout and retries etc.

```
def assert_results():
    response = request.get(some_url)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert len(response.json()['results']) == 10

polling.poll(assert_results, timeout=30, step=3)
```

This way I have to create lot of such functions for different tests but I want to retry those lines without a function like

```
with some_python_cool_feature(timeout=60, retry_interval=3):
    response = request.get(some_url)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert len(response.json()['results']) == 10
```

I thought, maybe we can do such things with context managers but I was not able to do that. Any help is most appreciated but I don't want a solution using some function and then calling that with some try catch.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the retrying package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retrying.
Just decorate your test with `@retry` and if it raises an error, it will retry.

```
@retry(stop_max_attempt_number=7)
def test_something():
    response = request.get(some_url)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert len(response.json()['results']) == 10
```

the `@retry` decorator receives many additional arguments for defining your retry functionality so you should be set.

Note that in your case this will specifically fail on an AssertionError exception.

Comment: I want to wait within test and retry some lines of code and not to try whole test again.

Comment: Why not define a nested function then which will have a retry decorator and only perform the relevant code until you get the response you're looking for?

Comment: if I have 100 tests and there are 30 unique types (lines of code) then I have to create nested functions every where. I have gone through all such solutions. Thanks BTW.

Comment: My pleasure.. but I don't see how this is different than a context manager. Anyhow, you can try https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redo/1.0 instead.

Comment: Nope... same as `retrying`, `retry`, `polling`. I want a solution that looks like context manager style of coding where we have a nested block of code which in my case , I want to retry in case of failure.